# Route Config MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I have a question about MVC routing. Given the route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Venda",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{automovelId}/{consumidorId}/{revendedoraId}",
    defaults: new {
        controller = "Venda",
        action = "Index",
        automovelId = UrlParameter.Optional,
        consumidorId = UrlParameter.Optional,
        revendedoraId = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);
```

I want to be able to call the Edit action like this:

```
/Venda/Edit/1/1/1
```

But it only works when called like this:

```
/Venda/Edit?automovelId=1&consumidorId=1&revendedoraId=1
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant use multiple optional parameters in a route. Only the last parameter can be optional.

Comment: Stephen Muecke, I have to remove the last two optional parameters?

Comment: @Yuri, This [blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/20/routing-regression-with-two-consecutive-optional-url-parameters.aspx/) will give you some more information on possible workarounds

Comment: I was looking this blog a few minutes ago. But I'm still having problems. The three parameters are my primary key.

Comment: @Yuri, Just remove `UrlParameter.Optional` from the first 2 parameters and then make sure that you pass those parameters when calling the action method

Comment: @Yuri, Here's an example `routes.MapRoute(name: "EmployeeTimeSheet",url: "Report/TimeSheet/{id}/{date}",defaults: new { controller = "Report", action = "TimeSheet"}` and the action method ` public ActionResult TimeSheet(int? id, DateTime? date)`

Comment: Still not working, I removed the last 2 parameters. The 3 parameters are being passed.

Comment: Finally worked. I organized the routes. First the routes with multiple parameters then the default route. I removed all the UrlParameter.Optional, because I have to pass all of them. Thanks a lot!